# image not centering using css

Tags: html, css, margin, centering

Newbie question here. Trying to learn the basics. I have a simple page with a header a footer and a container. In that container I want an image, and I want it centered. Using margin: 0 auto is not doing it. I have tried explicitly giving the container a width, still no good. Thanks.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#header {
  position: relative;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#container {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: red;
}

#imagewrap {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #818181;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 75%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"> </div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="imagewrap">
    <img src="Images/01Folder/Image.jpg" height="100%" id="front" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"> </div>
```

Comment: It's because you have placed your imagewrap absolutely - you would need to give it `left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cuxbv3z4/)

remove `position: absolute;` and add width to `imagewrap` class .like `width: 300px;`

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100vh;

}

#header {
    position: relative;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}


#footer {
    position: relative;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
}


#container {
    height: 80%;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: red;
}



#imagewrap{
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #818181;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 75%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
    <div id="header">
    </div>

      <div id="container">

      <div id="imagewrap">
        <img src="Images/01Folder/Image.jpg" height="100%" id="front" />
      </div>

      </div>

    <div id="footer">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `text-align: center;` instead of `margin: 0 auto;` to `imagewrap`

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100vh;

}
#header {
    position: relative;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#footer {
    position: relative;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: block;
}
#container {
    height: 80%;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: red;
}
#imagewrap{
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #818181;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 75%;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    </div>

      <div id="container">

      <div id="imagewrap">
        <img src="Images/01Folder/Image.jpg" height="100%" id="front" />
      </div>

      </div>

    <div id="footer">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try background image for that container and position it  center.
Please change background url as per your requirement

[image]

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100vh;    
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}    

#footer {
    position: relative;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

#container {
    height: 80%;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: red;
        

    background-image:  url(http://clockworkmoggy.com/wp-content/uploads/image00.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;

}     

#imagewrap{
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #818181;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 75%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
     </div>

      <div id="container">

      <div id="imagewrap">
       
      </div>

      </div>

    <div id="footer">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `margin:0 auto;` and replace  `text-align: center;` in `#imagewrap`. It will work!!
Check the below JSFiddle code for reference.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100vh;    
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}    

#footer {
    position: relative;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

#container {
    height: 80%;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: red;
}     

#imagewrap{
    
    border: 1px solid #818181;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 75%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <body>    
      <div id="header"> </div>     
      <div id="container">    
      <div id="imagewrap">
        <img src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/29708" height="100%" id="front" />
      </div>    
      </div>    
      <div id="footer"> </div>   
    </body>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sv3c5eyg/1/)